# Как задать свой формат <title> для постов в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 4.9, в шаблоне заголовок выводится внутри

```
wp_head();
```

В functions.php включена поддержка title-tag:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

На страницах получается title вида "%title — %sitename", нужно изменить его на свой только для определённого типа постов или шаблона, на всём остальном сайте сохранить такие как есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте фильтр `the_title`. Добавьте в `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_title', 10, 2 );
function my_title( $title, $id ) {
    // на основании $id поста примите решение, что делать с $title
    return $title;
}
```

Для того, чтобы изменить тег `<title>` в заголовке, используйте фильтр `pre_get_document_title`

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'my_pre_get_document_title' );
function my_pre_get_document_title() {
    global $post;

    if ( 957 === $post->ID ) { // 957 замените на id поста
        $title = 'New tiltle tag';
    }

    return $title;
}
```

Результат можете посмотреть у меня на тестовом сайте http://test.kagg.eu/so861733/

Comment: Так меняется заголовок страниц в меню, но <title> остаётся прежним

Comment: А у вас в вопросе ни слова про **тег** `<title>`. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Это именно то что нужно было. Уточнил заголовок вопроса.